# Hide ComboBox Toggle Button?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to make a generic `Style` in `<Window.Resources>` to allow me to set the visibility of the `ToggleButton` at the side. I can't find a specific question addressing this.

I made this `Style` below, but it seems to hide every `ComboBox` in the project even though I have set the trigger for only when `IsVisible` is true.

The code: This is my attempt at the style,

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsVisible, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And this is the main style for all the `CombBox` in the project,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">  
              <Grid>                       
                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" 
                     Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleStyle}">
                <....More styles below...>
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: The ControlTemplate of your ComboBoxToggleStyle is empty...this means that the ToggleButton has no "look". Exactly when and how do you want to hide the ToggleButton?

Comment: @mm8, when I set `IsVisible="True"` in the actual ComboBox XAML I want to disable the Toggle button.

Comment: Is IsVisible a custom property of yours? Because the built-in one cannot be set. It is read-only...

Comment: @mm8, Yes, I was trying set it here `<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsVisible` in `ComboBoxToggleStyle` Style.

Comment: You can't set the IsVisible property because it has no public setter. And you can't bind the Value property of a Setter so this will never work.

Comment: @mm8, ahh well, back to the drawing board then. Thanks for the help again. I may just have to live with the toggle button being on this particular combobox. Cheers

Comment: You could create  custom style where you remove the ToggleButton. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the `IsVisible` property because it has no public setter. And you can't bind the `Value` property of a `Setter` so this won't work.

What you could is set the `Style` property of the particular `ComboBox` for which you want to hide the `ToggleButton` to a `Style` that has a template that lacks a `ToggleButton`:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource styleWithoutToggleButton}" />
```

Comment: OK, I will see what I can do. Thanks for the point in the right direction.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I got it working using the way you suggested. It did not cross my mind to make two different styles. Thanks again for the help.